# Сортировка объектов datetime в python

Tags: python, сортировка, datetime

Задача заключается в подсчете времени, в которое горит лампочка, пока за ней смотрит наблюдатель. Из входных данных - отрезки включения и выключения лампочки, а также время наблюдения. Код выглядит так (знаю, громоздко):

```py
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List, Optional

def sum_light(els: List[datetime],
              start_watching: Optional[datetime] = None,
              end_watching: Optional[datetime] = None) -> int:
    if start_watching is None:
        start_watching = els[0]
    if end_watching is None:
        end_watching = datetime.max
    els = sorted(els + [start_watching] + [end_watching])
    start = els.index(start_watching)
    end = els.index(end_watching)
    if start_watching is not None and end_watching is None:
        return int(sum((on - off).total_seconds() for off, on in
                   zip(els[start + (start % 2 == 0)::2], els[start + (start % 2 == 0) + 1::2])))
    elif start_watching is None and end_watching is not None:
        return int(sum((on - off).total_seconds() for off, on in
                   zip(els[:end + 1:2], els[1:end + 1:2])))
    elif start_watching is not None and end_watching is not None:
        return int(sum((on - off).total_seconds() for off, on in
                   zip(els[start + (start % 2 == 0):end + 1:2], els[start + (start % 2 == 0) + 1:end + 1:2])))
    else:
        return int(sum((on - off).total_seconds() for off, on in
                   zip(els[::2], els[1::2])))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Example:")
    print(
          sum_light(
                    [
                      datetime(2015, 1, 12, 10, 0, 0),
                      datetime(2015, 1, 12, 10, 0, 10),
                    ],
                    datetime(2015, 1, 12, 10, 0, 0),
                    datetime(2015, 1, 12, 10, 0, 10),
                   )
         )
```

Следующий этап задачи - несколько лампочек (к входным данным добавляется номер лампочки, и теперь это объекты типа Tuple[datetime, int]. В коде могут быть как объекты tuple, так и просто объекты datetime, которые должны пониматься как первая лампочка (без индекса)).Код такой:

```py
def sum_light(
              els: List[Union[datetime, Tuple[datetime, int]]],
              start_watching: Optional[datetime] = None,
              end_watching: Optional[datetime] = None) -> int:
    if start_watching is None:
        start_watching = els[0]
    if end_watching is None:
        end_watching = datetime.max
    els = [(elem, 1) if type(elem) is datetime else elem for elem in els] # Здесь привожу все элементы к общему виду
    els = sorted(els + [start_watching] + [end_watching], key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
```

Но теперь, когда я пытаюсь отсортировать список по объекту `datetime` и индексу, интерпретатор ругается:

```py
els = sorted(els, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

> TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable

Почему в первом случае код спокойно отсортировал список по `datetime`, а во втором выскакивает ошибка?

Comment: Потому что во втором случае вы явно указываете, что ключ сортировки входит в некую последовательность (список, тупль и т.д.). Когда код проверяет, последовательность ли пришла - облом, потому что просто объект - не является последовательностью (subscriptable)

Comment: @MBo, cпасибо, вроде бы понял, в чем корень зла. Но все еще не понимаю, как в таком случае отсортировать список _els_ по объектам _datetime_ и _int_?

Comment: Чтобы сортировать с ключом, список должен быть однородным. Сделайте наблюдателя так же, как лампочку. Но не уверен, что ваш подход годится для множества лампочек. Задача, кстати, не сформулирована

Comment: @MBo вроде же описал задачу в начале? Или Вы про код? Задача заключается в том, чтобы выразить в секундах то время, пока горит хотя бы одна лампочка, и пока за ней наблюдает наблюдатель. Полное условие выражено тут: [https://py.checkio.org/en/mission/multiple-lightbulbs/].

Comment: Как узнать общее время, когда светло, если есть перекрытие интервалов: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1477585/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Досконально изучив возможности сортировки, понял, что кортежи можно отсортировать с помощью модуля *operator*. Задав оператору *itemgetter()* второй объект кортежа, а именно число (в моем случае номер лампочки), я смог отсортировать список так, чтобы включение и выключение каждой лампочки шло друг за другом, что дает мне возможность узнать время работы лампочки, поочередно вычитая время выключения из времени включения с помощью *zip*.