# Прохождение по кортежам в списке. python

Tags: python

Всем привет уже такой вопрос задавал но так и не нашел удовлетворяющий ответ.
Напишите функцию sum_of_segments, которая принимает список сегментов и возвращает сумму длин всех сегментов. Перекрытие сегментов должно учитываться только один раз. Сегменты — это пары целых чисел в формате кортежа, например: (2, 7) — это интервал от 2 до 7. Длина этого сегмента равна 5.

Список с перекрывающимися сегментами: [(2, 5), (8, 11), (4, 6)]. Сумма длин этих сегментов равна 7. Поскольку (2, 5) и (4, 6) перекрываются, мы можем рассматривать интервал как (2, 6), который имеет длину 4.
И главное функция должна работать не перегружая память если числа будут большими.
Примеры:
sum_of_segments([(1, 2), (6, 10), (11, 15)])
result is 9

sum_of_segments([(1, 4), (7, 10), (3, 5)])
result is 7

sum_of_segments([(1, 5), (10, 20), (1, 6), (16, 19), (5, 11)])
result is 19

sum_of_segments([(0, 25), (-999999999, 15), (52, 62)])
result is 100000034

```
fff = [(1, 17), (2, 15), (4, 14), (3, 16)]                                            
                                                                                      
def sum_my(segments):                                                                 
    new_list = segments                                                               
    new_list_tuples = []                                                              
    for i in range(len(new_list) - 1):                                                
        # если в списке у соседних кортежах 2е числа не равны при i+1                 
        if new_list[i][1] + 1 != new_list[i + 1][1]:                                  
            # то вычесляем разницу кортежа и добавляем в новый список                 
            new_list_tuples.append(new_list[i][1] - new_list[i][0])                   
            # если равны 2е числа +1                                                  
        if new_list[i][1] + 1 == new_list[i + 1][1]:                                  
            # и у первого кортежа первое число меньше или равно чем у второго кортежа 
            if new_list[i][0] <= new_list[i + 1][0]:                                  
                #                                                                     
                new_list_tuples.append(new_list[i + 1][1] - new_list[i][0])           
            else:                                                                     
                new_list_tuples.append(new_list[i + 1][1] - new_list[i + 1][0])       
                                                                                      
    print(new_list)                                                                   
    print(new_list_tuples)                                                            
    print(sum(new_list_tuples))                                                       
sum_my(fff)
```

Проблема я не могу понять как проверить на слияние если таких много в списке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из каждого сегмента сделайте две пары `(начало; +1)` и `(конец; -1)`. Сложите все пары в один список и отсортируйте его по первому полю.

Теперь задайте `active=0` и пройдите по списку. Для каждой пары добавляйте второе поле к `active`

Если `active` было 0, а стало 1, запомните позицию (`start = первое поле`)

Если `active` стало 0,  вычислите разность первого поля со `start` и добавьте к сумме длин.

В остальных случаях ничего не делать.

Всё.

Comment: Вопрос а как active может стать ноль если у меня (конец, -1)? или я не до конца понял

Comment: когда интервал кончается, счетчик уменьшается. если на данный момент все интервалы кончились, счетчик стал нулевым (2, 5), (4, 6) =>(2,1) (4,1) (5,-1) (6,-1).  счетчик меняется 0-1-2-1-0